Make bracket Highlights in IntelliJ transparent
Observe the images below:

This is from VS Code. in line 28, in new BufferedReader(fr)), the closing bracket (right before the comment) is highlighted with a small transparent rectangle.
Here's the same piece of code from IntelliJ.

I am unable to show the cursor location because cursor disappears in screenshots. But the thing is, here, it is in the same location (as it was when in VS Code). Here it is highlighted in a similar manner with  grey rectangle.
The problem is, this greyness makes it a little difficult to see where the cursor is. The greying happens whether the cursor is before or after the bracket. Which is quite a useful thing to know while programming: it helps to know if I'm inputting a parameter (if the cursor is before the bracket) or typing a semicolon (if the cursor is after the bracket).
Is there a way to make the bracket highlighter more transparent making it easier to see the cursor location?

You may like Rainbow brackets plugin

I already have it, that's not the issue. The area around the bracket becomes so cloudy that it was pretty difficult to see the cursor location.

So far, I have been able to figure this out until this level:

Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme. Under Code dropdown, select 'Matched brace' and add a suitable background and more importantly check the 'Effects' option and select Dotted Line from the respective dropdown. This makes the situation better, but I am not completely happy with the solution myself. If there's a way to make it as clear as it looks in VS Code, please let me know. Thanks
